# contentEditable, CTRL-B CTRL-I and saving

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've just started using a contentEditable, and have not found much comprehensive information on it.

I noticed that in Chrome, I can make words bold/italic by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>.

Is this possibly going to be the intended behavior in other browsers?  This, for instance, works in Chrome:

```
<div class="container" id="typer" onclick="this.contentEditable='true';">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uk6DA/15/

I'm wondering if I can read this formatting, in order to save the user's edits?  Also, can I create a Bold button and Italic button that will trigger <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>?  Or would I need to depend on the user pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (which means providing them a note telling them)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is standard in all major browsers. There are also programmatic equivalents of the keyboard shortcuts available via `document.execCommand()` in all major browsers, although in 2022 this seems to be on the way out. For now, bold and italic commands, for example, can executed as follows:

```
document.execCommand("Bold", false, null);
document.execCommand("Italic", false, null);
```

However, the mark-up generated varies between browsers. For example, variations for bold include `<b>foo</b>`, `<strong>foo</strong>` and `<span style="font-weight: bold">foo</span>`.

References:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [list of commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) (Mozilla)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  But do you know why this example (http://jsfiddle.net/uk6DA/15/) is not working in IE9?  At least ctrl-B and ctrl-I aren't.  Would the execCommands work?

Comment: Nevermind.  My own page works.  The JSFiddle page doesn't for some reason.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, I think that's a JSFiddle issue.

Comment: Does not appear to work in Firefox (v76, Linux). Ctrl+B brings up bookmarks, Ctril+I brings up page info, Ctrl+U brings up page source.

Comment: Is there an alternative to this? seems that document.execCommand is deprecated or on its way to be.. the MDN link^ is broken.. any updates?

Comment: @webkit: The alternatives are 1) creating/removing DOM elements yourself, which gets complicated to handle in anything but the simplest cases, or 2) use an existing editor.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer 'yes'.  You might find this [article](http://perplexed.co.uk/993_contenteditable_cross_browser_wysiwyg.htm) interesting.  Many a' developer have gone down this route.  If you want a nice wysiwyg editor, there are many to choose from.

On to your question: yes you can read the formatting.  Try an innerHTML on the element and you'll find `<b>` tags around your bolds and `<i>` around your italics.  Also - in the article I shared, you'll find out how to create a button that will bold.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could accept both answers but I could only accept one. :(

Comment: All good Dave!  His was more complete anyways.  Honestly I've played with contentEditable back in the day.  But there are so many successful and 'compatible' WYSIWYG editors out there - not much reason to reinvent the wheel.  Still rolling your own lightweight experience can be fun, interesting, and if your needs are light helpful.  Another problem with most WYSIWYG editors - they are an amalgamation of hacks for IE5, 6, etc.  Thank goodness we're moving into an IE8+ future :-)

Comment: I'm trying to create a unique UI.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can see which browsers support the contentEditable feature here:

https://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable

And as Tim Down said, you can call the `document.execCommand()` to bold or italicize things.

However, the keyboard shortcuts cannot be expected to be the same in all browsers, browser shortcuts are not standardized. <kbd>CTRL-B</kbd> for example is the bookmark shortcut in FireFox.